# How to display local image using Flash?

Tags: javascript, flash

Suppose that, I have local image path that get from `<input type="file"...` web control using javascript.

I want to pass this path to Flash object and display that image in it.

Comment: I would suggest using [flashvars](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=passingarguments_3.html), but we need more information from you. Is the flash object already loaded, or will it be loaded after you have the URL?

Comment: the flash object already loaded and it still display a default image.

Comment: I don't know your exact context, but it doesn't sound like flash is the best for the job here.

Comment: You can also create a flash project that imports external images on load and processes it inside the flash.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for info on is FlashVars. 
Flash Vars are ways to pass data to swf files. Very similar to Query Strings.
They size limit is 64k and are support on Flash Player 6 and newer I believe.
[Here](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/164/tn_16417.html) is the adobe site on them.

I hope this helps some